# Retrofit Android add new row in MySQL

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, retrofit

I am using **Retrofit** library in my project, to add a row in **MySQL** DB, and I have some problems with **@POST method**.

This is my PHP code in file **test_retro_post.php** on server with POST method:

```
<?php
$response = array();
if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price'])) {

$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test_retro(id, name, price) VALUES('$id', '$name', '$price')");


if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";


    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {

$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Sending usual HttpRequest with custom JSONparser, everything is working:

```
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));

        // getting JSON Object
        // url_create_product is URL to my PHP file with POST method


        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);
```

But something wrong when using Retrofit. The new row is not added. 
This is interface **Api_post.java** with **Retrofit`s @POST method**:

```
 public interface Api_post{
    @POST("/test_retro/test_retro_post.php")
   Call<RequestBody> createProd(@Body RequestBody body);
```

My RequestBody class (RequestBody.java):

```
public class RequestBody{
  int id;
  String name;
  int price;

RequestBody(int id, String name, int price){
    this.id=id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

And finally calling Retrofit in activity:

```
 Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Url.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build(); 
  Api_post api_post = restAdapter.create(Api_post.java);
  Call<RequestBody> call = api_post.createProd(new RequestBody(3, "prod_3", 300);
```

And then execute this call in AsyncTask:

```
call.execute();
```

The new row in MySQL DB isn`t added. Please tell me what is wrong with this code? Maybe i need custom converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is expecting data sent to it as POST parameters, but you are trying to send it JSON.  You can either change the server to accept JSON, or change retrofit to send POST parameters using the [`@Field`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/http/Field.html) annotation.  Also, pretty sure you want the response type to be `ResponseBody`, not `RequestBody`

```
@POST("/test_retro/test_retro_post.php")
Call<ResponseBody> createProd(@Field("id") int id, @Field("name") String name, @Field("price") int price);
```

call with -

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = api_post.createProd(3, "prod_3", 300);
```